# postfix feed to program as root

Tags: linux, security, postfix, permissions

I'm trying to get postfix to pipe `stdin` from an email into a script that needs to be run by `root` (yes I understand the security issues of doing this. no lectures, please).

Content of aliases file

```
myalias: |/root/script/thing.rb
```

Executable script `/root/script/thing.rb` needs to be run as `root`, but is currently ran as `nobody` by postfix.

Any ideas for a workaround?

any attempts at running a root script with postfix results in:

```
localhost postfix[942]: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter mail_owner: user root has privileged user ID
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem also occurs when you must let dovecot-lda talk with postfix. On [this documentation](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LDA#multipleuids), the author suggest two solutions

1. Make dovecot-lda setuid-root
2. Use sudo to wrap the invocation of dovecot-lda.

Option one was [well explained by coincoin](https://serverfault.com/a/446076/218590). The second one will be explained below.

1. For do that, you should have dedicated user to do sudo. Let assumet the user is `rubypostfix`.
2. Set new alias file /etc/postfix/aliasruby, chown to `rubypostfix` and put the alias.

   content of `/etc/postfix/aliasruby`

   ```
   myalias: | sudo /root/script/thing.rb
   ```

   Then set the owner. By default, postfix will pipe email to program with the [privilege same as alias file owner](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#aliases).

   ```
   chown rubypostfix /etc/postfix/aliasruby
   ```

   Don't forget to run `postalias` this file.
3. Then edit `/etc/sudoers` to allow this user execute only your ruby script.

   ```
   rubypostfix          ALL=NOPASSWD:/root/script/thing.rb
   ```

Comment: In fact this is a really good example for the usage of sudo and the possible rules in the sudoers-file with it's possibility to give permissions on file-location-basis.

Answer (score 1):

"(yes I understand the security issues of doing this. no lectures, please)" : Sorry, but I have to add one because you should understand the solution is really really dirty from a security point of view.

Here's a solution, but **I really advise you not to use it** :

```
chown root:root /root/script/thing.rb 
chmod 4755 /root/script/thing.rb
```

Now, this is really really bad because anyone in your system can execute `/root/script/thing.rb` with root privilege. That also means any little coding error in `/root/script/thing.rb` can allow anyone to gain root privilege on your system.

Note: /root/script/thing.rb is "setuid root".

Comment: I get that opening the permissions of a file up would allow any user to run the script. the trick is getting `postfix` (what the question is actually about) to run a root script.

Comment: Does your script needs to be ran by user root (uid is checked inside the script) or does your script needs to run with root privileges?

Comment: as `root`. I installed `rvm` under root, so all of the `gem`s can only be accessed by `root`. setting 4755 lets postfix's `nobody` user execute the program, but since root has access to all of the gems, it throws require "not found" errors. I think I've just gotta bite the bullet and create a new user and setup rvm again.

Comment: "setting 4755 lets postfix's nobody user execute the program" : No 0755 would do that. 4755 does it AND make postfix execute the program as root. There must be missing some environnement variables (hint : "printenv", "env" and "export" as root)